# swift scene.sks file objects not applying z rotation value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm making a simple game application for IOS devices, loosely based from the book 'swift game development'. I have created a protocol which I use as a template for creating a class for each type of in game object. A platform for the player to jump on has the following class based on the protocol

```
import SpriteKit
  class GrassyPlatform: SKSpriteNode, GameSprite {
  var textureAtlas:SKTextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Enviroment")
  var initialSize: CGSize = CGSize(width:630, height:44)   
  init() {     
      super.init(texture: textureAtlas.textureNamed("GrassPlatform1"), color: .clear, size: initialSize)
      self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y:0.5)
      physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: initialSize)
      physicsBody?.restitution = 0
      self.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false     
  } 
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }  
}
```

I'm using the scene editor to place these objects onto the scene, assigning each object the relevant custom class. Like the one above.
When I run the game the objects position (assigned only from the scene editor) is respected, but the zRotation value is ignored. For example setting the platform in the scene editor as so 
[image: gamescene screen shot]

But this results in the platform appearing at the correct position but with the default zRotation value and not the one assigned in the game scene.

[image: simulation screen shot]

I can adjust the rotation manually through self.zRotation but this defeats the whole point of using the scene.sks for level design.

Is there away to adjust the zRotation through game scene and if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem was in a piece of code that I never added to the original post because I 'thought' it was irrelevant! boy was I wrong. Another class handles the different scenes. This code I took from the book and was not 100% on its operation when I added it, before getting caught up in something else

```
class EncounterManager {
let encounterNames:[String] = ["Level1A", "Level1B"]     //A array of all the scenes in the level
var encounters:[SKNode] = []                                //each scene is a node
var currentEncounterIndex:Int?
var previousEncounterIndex:Int?

init() {
    for encounterFileName in encounterNames {                               //Loop all scenes in the scene array
        let encounterNode = SKNode()                                        //create a new node for the encounter/scene
        if let encounterScene = SKScene(fileNamed: encounterFileName) {     //load the encounter to the skscene
            for child in encounterScene.children {                          //Loop through each child node of the skscene
                let copyOfNode = type(of: child).init()                     //copy the node type and initilize to the encounterNode
                copyOfNode.position = child.position                        //copy the position
                copyOfNode.zPosition = child.zPosition                      //copy of zPosition
                copyOfNode.name = child.name                                //copy the name
                encounterNode.addChild(copyOfNode)                          //add child to encounter node
            }
        }
        encounters.append(encounterNode)
        //Save initial sprite positions for this encounter
        saveSpritePositions(node: encounterNode)
    }
}
```

This takes a copy of each object node and adds it to the game scene. The origonal author never needed to worry about the rotation of objects. So I added this and it worked

```
                    copyOfNode.zRotation = child.zRotation         //copy of zRotation
```

Thanks anyway if you looked.